# Write access only to specific bitbucket branch for external developer?

Tags: bitbucket

Is it possible to give an external developer write permissions to a specific branch only in bitbucket?

I just tried and somehow I can only choose the external developer when I give him Write access to the whole repository. When I switch his rights to Read for the repository, the branch write rights are removed ...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use the fork-and-merge-request model popularised by GitHub?

Comment: I also think that forks are the way to go here.

Comment: I believe that may not be a suggested solution for a private repo as the forked copy could then be made public, right?